# Spring Security PreAuthentication Token Exception

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring 4.2.5 MVC REST Back-End with Spring Security 4.0.4, and I am using the "SiteMinder" example where I am expecting an authentication token.

```
<beans:bean id="tokenFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="principalRequestHeader" value="auth_token"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">

<beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
        <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"  class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
            <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>

</beans:bean>
```

I do have a "userDetailsService" details class, and this is working as expected for me, and the unit tests do not fail. However, I do want some exceptions, like for the. login pages and the like.

So, here is part of my spring-security.xml file:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/test/getStat/**" access="hasRole('WEB')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/test/getData/**" access="hasRole('WEB')" />

<intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
<intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
<intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

 <intercept-url pattern="/login/user/*/pwd/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

<intercept-url pattern="/index.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
<intercept-url pattern="index.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

I've tried access="permitAll" and "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" and several other tricks.   It seems like every URL wants the token ... I just want url's to skip that check.   So, not sure what I am missing.

Any help would be much appreciated.